# Is there any way to export a Table to a spread sheet by having exported file data sorted the way that the Access table was?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have this “Order Details” table which is sorted based on “[Product Quantity]” in Z-A order and then [SKU] in A-Z.
I used below code to export.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, “Order Details ", FLocation & "\ Order Details ", True, , True
```

Even though the table is sorted, the output file has never got arranged the way the table is sorted.
I know there is a way to export using SQL String, but I wasn’t successful on my previous attempts(May be i don't know how it should be written). can anybody shed some light on this matter? 
Looking forward to hear from you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's funny I'm answering my own question. In case you are reading this and you are seeking solutions for a slimier scenario then the below steps are for you.

First instead of exporting the exact Table i have written a select query which will select all fields and sort records the way i wanted. below is the image and SQL statement.

```
SELECT [Delhivery Shipping List].* FROM [Delhivery Shipping List] ORDER BY [Delhivery Shipping List].[Product Quantity] DESC , [Delhivery Shipping List].SKU;
```

[image: Create Query Window]

Then i used this select query name in the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet command.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Query Delhivery Manifest Format", FileLocation & "\Delhivery Manifest", True, , True
```

That is all you have to do to get your exported excel file sorted. Please excuse me for the difference in table names that i mentioned in both question and answer.

Hope this will help you as well.